# I need to build a script to run some command line queries, and change out the variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like the below script to check multiple network shares, report back the newest files created on those shares to a csv file, (for import into a spreadsheet application).

Batchfile example:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET SystemName=NameHere
SET Path=PathHere 
for /f %%i in ('dir \\%SystemName%\"%Path%" /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo %LAST% >> C:\Filecheck.CSV
```

I have a separate spreadsheet compatible csv file with a list of system names and file paths I would like queried in this manner.

I'm trying to figure out how to get a batch file to reference specific records in the csv when performing a looped query on each value.

I hope somebody more seasoned than me in creating this type of script can provide some expertise.

Comment: `%PATH%` is already a system variable name; please don't change it.

Comment: The problem you are tyring to solve seems too broad for a script to handle

Comment: Compo, I appreciate the feedback. But I'm not asking anyone to modify or write my code. I'm asking them for direction. Should this be a PowerShell script, can it be captured in a batch file? If This site is not the appropriate place for that type of question, I apologize. I can go somewhere else. Replies like yours make me not want to use the services on this site.

Comment: Samisa, I was thinking along the same lines. This endeavor may be too broad for a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory,
rem filenames, and output filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
:: your server,pathname file
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q73198775.txt"
:: your csv data file
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

TYPE nul>>"%outfile%"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=," %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 ECHO processing %%c ON %%b
 FINDSTR /i /v /b /L /c:"%%b,%%c," "%outfile%" > "%outfile%.tmp"
 SET "reported=N"
 for /f "delims=" %%e in ('dir /b/a-d/o-d/t:c "\\%%b\%%c" 2^>nul') do IF DEFINED reported SET "reported="&>>"%outfile%.tmp" ECHO %%b,%%c,%%e
 MOVE /y "%outfile%.tmp" "%outfile%" >NUL 2>nul
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Assuming that the system names,file paths file is like

```
system1,path1
system2,path1
system1,path2
```

Then first append nothing to the .csv data file (creates an empty file if the file does not already exist.)

Read the servers file, assigning servername to `%%b` and path to `%%c` and foe each one found,

use `findstr` to find the line of the output .csv file that `/b` starts `/i` case-insensitive  `/L` literally `/c:"this string" and` /v`report all non-matches. The string supplied is`server,path,`so any existing line for`server,path` is deleted. The result is sent to a temporary file.

Set the `reported` flag to `N` and process the `dir` report sorted in *reverse*-date order. When the first (ie *latest*) filename is found, `reported` is set, so clear `reported` and report the filename in `%%e`.

Finally, move the temporary file with the modified data over the original.

Comment: Wow, this is way more than I was expecting. I greatly appreciate it I'm going to try this, and I hope it works. I'll let you know how it shakes out.